# Why does AngularJS Material suppresses uncaught exceptions in $mdDialog controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

In my current $mdDialog.controller I accidentally try to access the .forEach property (expecting it to be an array) of undefined.

Figuring this out, I had to debug the code, because the uncaught expection does not log to the console. It is catched in here in AngularJS:

[image]

**My question**

Why are uncaught exceptions not logged to $log.error and then to the console by AngularJS's [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler)?